# Can't change modules buildVariant

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-library, android-productflavors

I have a project with a main app and 3 modules. They depend on each other like

```
app (android application)
 |
 --- module1 (android library)
       |
       --- module2 (android library)
             |
             --- module3 (android library)
```

I'm using AS 3.0 with BuildTool 3.0.0-alpha5.
I applied changes described in the doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_dependencies

Here is my
**build.gradle** (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        qa {}
        release {}
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {dimension = "default"}
        flavor2 {dimension = "default"}
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':module1')
    ...
}
```

Here is my
**build.gradle** (module1)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        qa {}
        release {}
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':module2')
    ...
}
```

Here is my
**build.gradle** (module2)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        qa {}
        release {}
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':module3')
    ...
}
```

---

My problem: my app is set on "**flavor1Debug**" but all my modules variants are stuck on "**qa**". I can't switch them to "debug" in the BuildVariant window.

I have a Gradle Sync warning:

> Warning:
> Module 'module1' has variant 'debug' selected, but the module
>   ''app'' depends on variant 'qa'
> Select 'module1'
>   in "Build Variants" window

Is anyone have an idea of what I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest AS3.0 canary 8 fixed this issue

Answer (score 2):

You can change the inside of the panel build variant.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: I know, I tried. 
Actually the latest update fixed the issue AS3.0 canary 8